# Can a server ignore PHP curl sessions?

Tags: php, curl

It looks like a webserver is ignoring my cookies. (used in PHP curl)

Getting the cookies works fine, but returning doesn't work. When I go to the website with my browser and remove the cookies I get the exact same behaviour.

How can I solve this? Does it have anything to do with the https?

Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/createAccount.jsp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/var/www/ajax/Cache/Sessions/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  "/var/www/ajax/Cache/Sessions/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('_dyncharset' => 'UTF-8',
              '_DARGS' => '/createAccount.jsp',
              'firstName'        => $firstname,
              'login'            => $email,
              'lastName'         => $lastname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://example.com/createAccount.jsp?action=createAccount');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/var/www/ajax/Cache/Sessions/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  "/var/www/ajax/Cache/Sessions/cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: does the script have write access (filesystem) to the cookie jar / file ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "returning doesn't work?" Do you mean the remote server doesn't recognize the cookies on the second request?

Comment: try different values for `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` (don't make it the same file)

Comment: @DanFromGermany the cookiefile is where it reads cookies from cookiejar is where it saves. they should be same ...

Comment: what's the best way to determine that? A simple `fread()` is able to load the file....

Comment: `file_put_contents("/var/www/blabla" , "test");`

Comment: @n00b no, the one saves actual cookie data (session), the other saves offline data

Comment: @DanFromGermany http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html#Cookies_with_libcurl

Comment: @n00b wow ok,... I then find the information on php.net misleading. thx for the link

Comment: Thanks, it's so strange though, I keep getting a HTTP Status 409. Also when I use my browser and remove cookies

Comment: perhaps the cookie is protected from tampering (example - `$cookie = $cookie.'-'.sha1($cookie.'$ecr3t_v4lu3');` ). also it is possible you MUST have a cookie set, or there is a cache proxy (varnish?) before the actual server that requires a cookie to be set.

Comment: @n00b that could be possible, but I'm not sure how to find a solution for this. Can you help me a little bit more?

Comment: When I disable cookies in my browser I get the exact same output...

Answer (score 2):

make sure the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` file is writeable by the server process (that executes the php script).

if that fails you can simply re-use the same instance of curl just drop the

```
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove below line from your first curl request. And it should work for you:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/var/www/ajax/Cache/Sessions/cookie.txt");
```

`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` is used to send cookie to server from a file. So removing this line will mean sending no cookie. So server will not notice any previous visit :-)